# R tabulate with if statement

Tags: r, if-statement, latex

I would like to tabulate a variable in a data frame only if it is below a certain percentile.
For example I would like a table of variable X for all rows such that X is below the 95% percentile of that variable.
How can I do this....?
I would also like to output this to Latex, both the proportion and count variables (i.e. prop.table and table outputs)
Thanks!

Comment: To get a table of `iris`, with `iris$Sepal.Length` less than or equal to 95 percentile of its value: `iris[iris$Sepal.Length <= quantile(iris$Sepal.Length, .95),]`

Comment: thanks, I guess I wasn't clear. by table I meant a tabulation table. as in table(x) or prop.table(x). I want to do this for many variables which is why I did not want to just make a new data table based on the percentile of one variable in particular.